# How to compare big objects with FluentAssertsions?

Tags: integration-testing, assert

I am doing integrative xunit tests on a .NET Core web application. The result of a call can sometimes be a large object with different levels of hierarchy.

```
     MainEntity
     {
        public decimal TotalTaxValue{ get; set; }

        public decimal GrossPrice{ get; set; }

        public List<Taxes> GroupedTotal { get; set; }

        //..... 20 more properties
      }

      Taxes 
      {

        public List<TaxCode> TaxCodes {get;set;}

        public decimal TaxedAmount{get;set;}
      }

    TaxCode 
    {
     public string TaxCodeType {get;set;} //VAT / EGAT

     public string ApplicableRegion {get;set;}
     }
```

Now when doing tests (using FluentAssertions) I end up with many lines of

```
item.PropertyName.Should().Be(output.PropertyName, because: "reason")
```

Also when going to compare the lists of objects inside the models, I found a few not nice to look at linq statements (which spread across multiple lines).

I should mention I don't have access to modify the original model and override the equals method.

Looking at how my code, with 10+ lines of assertions for a single test it can't be the best approach.

Another way I thought of approaching this would be to have a method to handle all of the assertions - but this only hides the issue. Also doing a test for each property, to avoid multiple assertions in a test, would be very time consuming, both in developing the tests and execution.

**Question:**

What are the best practices when comparing/(performing assertions on) larger objects in terms of assertions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an solution for comparing larger objects (specific to my case, since it's actually part of FluentAssertions).

> https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/

From the documentation, it compares with a recursion of 10 levels and it it's used like this:

```
orderDto.Should().BeEquivalentTo(order);
```

I submit that a best practice to compare large objects is to use such a library if the objects don't have an equality comparer. This way you don't alter business code (by adding methods for testing) and not need multiple asserts in a test.